# Webservice delivering pdfs

Tags: web-services, pdf

For a proof-of-concept I am looking for a webservice that delivers dummy PDF files. Do you know by chance one ?

I googled but did not find anything.

Comment: What is a "dummy PDF"? Do you have an example of a dummy PDF?

Comment: a "dummy PDF" would be just a PDF file (this could be a blank one). I know that there are webservices to which you pass parameters and get a response, for instance json or xml. The idea would be the same but a webservice delivering PDF files